# TF-IDF vectorizer with python

Tags: python, vectorization, tf-idf, tfidfvectorizer

I have a problem with the TfidfVectorizer function in python. 
For example if I have a string like this one:
'xxx//xx. aaa.bb.ccc.d'
will be extracted these words as the key of the dictionary:
'xxx', 'xx', 'aaa', 'bb', 'ccc', 'd'
instead, I want to create these new features:
'xxx//xx.' , 'aaa.bb.ccc.d'

How can I ask to TfidfVectorizer function to select words separated by the space (' ')?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at:
https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html

There is a parameter called token-pattern.

Answer (score 0):

`token-pattern` parameter in TfidfVectorizer  used to specify custom split pattern

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
a = ['xxx//xx. aaa.bb.ccc.d']  
t = TfidfVectorizer(token_pattern=r"([a-z]*//[a-z]*)|([a-z.]*)")
```

Ouputs

```
[('', ''), ('', '.'), ('', 'aaa.bb.ccc.d'), ('xxx//xx', '')]
```

Some post cleaning is required in this case.

Comment: Thank you, but I still have a problem. I have a lot of different words with a lot of different special characters. For example, I have some words like this one: \\\\x64\\\\x61\\\\x64\\\\x64\\\\x79\\\\x6C\\\\x33\\\\x33\\\\x74 and many others different. I cannot write all the patterns because I cannot control all the corpus. There is no function for discriminate one word from another based on the space?

Comment: You might have to preprocess and create vocabulary of words. then include in Tfidfvectorizer.. If space is the key to split, create list of sentence and create countvectorizer and convert to TfidfTransformer.